# Can't call a function properly from switch, can't recall a function

Tags: c, function, switch-statement

I have some problems with my code. At first when I want to call a function from a switch statement it won't work. I mean the function is calling but the fgets and stdin doesn't work. If I call the same function alone in main, all works properly. And the other problem is that when I want to recall the same function in else statement. I want to recall the function just once when the password (or nickname) is wrong but it recalls several times, usually quite random times.

```
void passcheck(){

    char password[11];
    int up,num;

    puts("Password (max 10 signs, must contain upperletter and number):");
    fgets(password, 10, stdin);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if (isupper(password[i])) {
            up=1;
        }
        if (isdigit(password[i])){
            num=1;
        }
    }
    if (num == 1 && up == 1){
        printf("Your password is good and looks like:\n%s\n", password);
    }
    else{
        puts("Correct you password");
        passcheck();
    }
}

void nickname(){

    char nick[11];
    int up,num;

    puts("Type your nickname (must contain upperletter):");
    fgets(nick, 10, stdin);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if (isupper(nick[i])) {
            up=1;
        }
    }
    if (num == 1){
        printf("Your nickname is good and it is:\n%s\n", nick);
    }
    else{
        puts("Correct nickname");
        nickname();
    }
}


void what_to_do(){
    int number;
    puts("What do you want to do?\n 1. Check password \n 2. Check nickname");

    scanf("%d", &number);
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            passcheck();
            break;
        case 2:
            nickname();
            break;
        default:
            puts("Wrong sign!");
            break;
    }
}
int main(){

    what_to_do();

    //passcheck();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you type in?

Comment: void what_to_do() should be void what_to_do(void), other functions as well

Comment: Exactly what do you enter at the prompt when the program prompts you, and exactly what did you then see?

Comment: `fgets(password, 10, stdin);` --> `fgets(password, 11, stdin);`, `int up,num;` --> `int up = 0, num = 0;`, at `nickname` `if (num == 1){` --> `if (up == 1){`

Comment: `scanf("%d", &number);` --> `scanf("%d%*c", &number);` or `scanf("%d", &number); while(getchar()!='\n');`

Comment: In `nickname()` you write `up=1` but never use `up`; and you test `num == 1` but `num` is an uninitialized variable

Answer (score 0):

All your problems are related to how the input handling works from the standard input: it is handled as a stream of characters, while the data is sent from the terminal only when you press the enter key which adds a new line character to the stream.

Your code is not expecting a new line character and interprets it as part of the input which leads to the explained side effects.

You must consume or remove the new line character every time when you read from the standard input. It is explained here why this happens and what can you do to avoid it in full details:

http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-60.html

Comment: Also: whenever you need to debug your code it is always a good idea to dump the input what you are about to process. If you would add this line into your code after reading the password: ``printf("input: '%s'", password);`` then you would see immediately that the new line character is added into your input feed.

Comment: ^^ what @racs says.  It's called debugging.  If you cannot debug, you cannot program computers.